# pp not working on ruby file

Tags: ruby, fold, perl-packager

**How do I get pp to wrap (limit) the line lengths to 79 characters as the [pp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html) documentation says?**

The following example demonstrates that pp does not limit the output to default length 79 as stated in the [pp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html) documentation.

- (1) Put the following code into a file (pprfile.rb).

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env ruby
> require 'pp'
> STDIN.read.split("\n").each do |l|
>   PP.pp(l)
> end
> ```

- (2) Clone the Github typo [code](https://github.com/fdv/typo/blob/master/app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb) repo and cd into the repo directory.
- (3) Run the following command line:

  - pprfile.rb < ./app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb | awk 'length($0) > 79 { print length($0), $0 }'
- (4) I expected all of the output lines to be limited to less than or equal 79 characters, but here is what I I got as output:

> ```
> 89 "      redirect_back_or_default :controller => \"admin/dashboard\", :action => \"index\""
> 94 "      self.current_user = User.authenticate(params[:user][:login], params[:user][:password])"
> 82 "          self.current_user.remember_me unless self.current_user.remember_token?"
> 82 "        add_to_cookies(:typo_user_profile, self.current_user.profile_label, '/')"
> 91 "        redirect_back_or_default :controller => \"admin/dashboard\", :action => \"index\""
> 80 "    @page_title = \"#{this_blog.blog_name} - #{_('Recover your password')}\""
> 124 "      @user = User.find(:first, :conditions => [\"login = ? or email = ?\", params[:user][:login], params[:user][:login]])"
> 108 "        flash[:notice] = _(\"An email has been successfully sent to your address with your new password\")"
> 88 "    redirect_to(:controller => \"accounts\", :action => \"signup\") if User.count == 0"
> 92 "    redirect_to :controller => \"setup\", :action => \"index\" if  ! this_blog.configured?"</li>
> ```

Comment: Without samples of your input and what the output looks like we're guessing at the problem.

Comment: Tin Man: Did the example help?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess because "pp" breaks only *between* atomic data elements, not *within* them.  An atomic element would be a non-composite type (e.g. a string, symbol, number, etc).

That is, if you have an array whose serialized elements would exceed 79 columns then "pp" will serialize the array with linebreaks between elements.  However, if one of those elements was a string of 100 chars then that element will be serialized as-is, presumably because "pp" doesn't want to decide where to break that "atomic" element.

Consider:

```ruby
pp(Array.new(100, 'foo')) # => <breaks between each element>
pp('x' * 100) # => <displays on one line since it doesn't know where to break>
```